# Possible bug in ImageFeatureTrack?

Tags: dynamic, image-processing, animation

I'm using `ImageFeatureTrack` to track several moving simple objects in a series of images, but sometimes it will fail to track stuffs, and why it fail is always a mystery to me:

This phenomenon can be easily illustrated by the following case of tracking the four corners of a simple moving `Rectangle`:

```
i = Table[
   Rasterize[
    Graphics[Rectangle[{-.9 + k .05, -.5}, {.1 + k .05, .5}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], ImageSize -> {100, 100}], {k, 
    0, 16}];

ListAnimate@i

ImageFeatureTrack[
 First /@ Partition[i, 4], {{6, 74}, {54, 74}, {6, 26}, {54, 26}}]

ImageFeatureTrack[{i[[1]], 
  i[[1]]}, {{6, 74}, {54, 74}, {6, 26}, {54, 26}}]
```

the first returns:

> {{{6., 74.}, {54., 74.}, {6., 26.}, {54., 26.}}, {Missing[], {63.9868, 74.0008}, Missing[], {63.9875, 26.0003}}, {Missing[], {73.9786, 73.9991}, Missing[], {73.978, 26.0037}}, {Missing[], {83.9614, 73.9959}, Missing[], {83.9597, 26.0084}}}

`ImageFeatureTrack` simply missed all corner 1 and 3 whill correctly tracked corner 2 and 4.

To make things wierder, in the second trial showing two **IDENTICAL** image, `ImageFeatureTrack` missed corner 1 and 3!!!

Am I missing something or it's simply a misbehaviour of `ImageFeatureTrack`?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes it is strange ... It works though if you just add the option `MaxFeatureDisplacement -> {1, 1}` ! (whatever actually these values are: {0.1,0.1} or {2,1}, ... but NOT too large like {20,20})

Comment: @SquareOne That's truely wierd, the displacement in the first example is obviously larger than 1 pixel in each and every step. and in the second example, whatever this value is shouldn't effect the result as the displacement is 0!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sequence, the first image has 2 corners that are too close to the boundary and `ImageFeatureTrack` has troubles tracking those.

If you rerun your experiments with added padding, things work as expected: `i = ImagePad[#, 20, 1] & /@ i;`

Also, in its current implementation `ImageFeatureTrack` is effectively dismissing specified coordinates that are not good enough to track. If your corner positions are specified a bit off, you may not be able to track them.